# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when connecting to an old web service

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, ssl-certificate

I need to connect to an old web service. It's a government service so I cannot do anything server side.

Firstly, when I try to connect to WSDL through browser, Chrome says:

> This site can't provide a secure connection. 'Site' uses and unsupported protocol.

> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Then, I inspected the server using [SSL Labs Server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). It confirmed that server only supports TLS1.0 and SSL3. SHA1withRSA 1024 bit is used. Actually, I did this much later during my troubleshooting but I think it's best to say it at the beginning.

Also, the server certificate expired in 2014, and it has a Common Name linked to a private address.

When I connect to the service in the Visual Studio 2019 I get:

[image]

After that, Visual Studio somehow had connected to the service and generated client classes.

But only once. I tried several more times, and I always get:

[image]

Now, I have searched throughout StackOverflow and elsewhere, and I applied many of the proposed solution, so this is my code so far:

```
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls; // TLS 1.0
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

var binding = new ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
var endpoint = new ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(url);

var client = new wsClient(binding, endpoint); // This is where code breaks
```

When using Ssl3 protocol I am getting following error:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to '...'. This
> could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
> protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
> aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
> server logs for more details.

And, when using Tls protocol I am getting:

> Exception: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with
> authority '...' InnerExeption: The request was aborted: Could not
> create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Also, when using Tls11, Tls12 or Tls13 I am getting the same error as when using only Tls.

The ServerCertificateValidationCallback never gets called, I assume the connection never reaches that point.

I have also tried connecting to the service using SoapUI. And it response was (after configuring it to even try TLS1.0):

> Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

So, I am really stuck and I have exhausted everything that I have found on the net. I would appreciate a suggestion or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everybody know, if somebody should ever stumble upon issue like this.
This is what I needed to do:

1. TLS1 and SSL3 were disabled at OS level, I needed to enable them there first.
2. Since it was very old service, I needed to import the service as a WebServiceReference that inherits SoapHttpClientProtocol, not as new ServiceReference that inherits ServiceBase.
3. Service required client certificates to be sent with each request.

Just in case anybody needs it.